# don't work <input type="file" ... when i want download file. Added html with anguldar js <ng-include>

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

i add html block to page using ng-include:

```
 <div ng-include="'/components/spare-parts-page/modals/spare-part-photos-modal.html'"></div>
```

but now don't work input field:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><label><i class="mr-1 bi bi-cloud-plus"></i><input style="display: none" type="file" id="spare_part_photo" name="photo_before" accept="image/*" multiple/>Добавить фото</label></a>
```

after click a didn't see modal with my file for change

my code:

```
<div ng-include="'/components/spare-parts-page/modals/spare-part-photos-modal.html'"></div>
```

modal:

```
`<div class="modal fade" id="spare-part-photo-modal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header badge-light">
                <h5 class="modal-title h4 font-italic">Фото запчасти {{selectedSparePart.name}}</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body font-italic">
                <div class="row mt-2 justify-content-end">
                    <div class="col-auto">
                        <div class="btn-group dropleft">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle shadow-sm font-italic" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Действия</button>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" ng-click="actionWithPhoto(true)"><i class="mr-1 bi bi-list-check"></i>Выделить все</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" ng-click="actionWithPhoto(false)"><i class="mr-1 bi bi-list-ul"></i>Снять выделение</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><label><i class="mr-1 bi bi-cloud-plus"></i><input style="display: none" type="file" id="spare_part_photo" name="photo_before" accept="image/*" multiple/>Добавить фото</label></a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" ng-click="deleteSelectedPhotos()"><i class="mr-1 bi bi-trash text-danger"></i>Удалить выбранные</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="alert alert-info mt-2" ng-show="!sparePartsPhotos.length">
                    <span>Фотографии не найдены</span>
                </div>
                <div class="row mt-2 row-cols-3">
                    <div class="row my-1 ml-1 align-items-center" ng-repeat="ph in sparePartsPhotos">
                        <div class="col-auto pr-0">
                            <div class="custom-control custom-switch d-inline">
                                <input class="custom-control-input shadow-sm" id="{{ph.id}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="ph._selected"><label class="custom-control-label" for="{{ph.id}}"></label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <img class="rounded" ng-src="/spare-part-photo/show-photo/{{ph.uid}}" alt="{{ph.name}}" title="{{ph.name}}" style="width: 180px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`
My code worked when i used th:replace instead ng-include

I need help! I dont know how fix it